# How can I do Exchange data of two labels on drag and drop in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I want to do something like 
 I have two **Labels**

A              ..............               ...........   B
______    ...........   _______
|  RED   |    .......... | GREEN  |
 ----------   ..........      -----------

When I drag *A* on *B* OR *B* on *A* the text of both exchange

A              ..............               ...........   B
______    ........... ...   _____
|  GREEN|    .......... | RED |
 ----------   ............... ---------

I have done a little of it

main window
[image: main window]

When I drag and drop the text from the **code** comes on the drop label

When I drag red on green:
[image: When I drag red on green]

**My Code:**

```
    private void Label_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblFrom = e.Source as Label;


        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lblFrom, lblFrom.Content, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void Label_QueryContinueDrag(object sender, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblFrom = e.Source as Label;

        if (!e.KeyStates.HasFlag(DragDropKeyStates.LeftMouseButton))
            lblFrom.Content = "RED";

    }

    private void Label_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string draggedText = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);

        Label toLabel = e.Source as Label;
        toLabel.Content = draggedText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I achieved it.

Below is my XAML.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Width="50" Height="50" Background="Red" Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown" Drop="Label_Drop" AllowDrop="True"/>
    <Label Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green" Content="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown" Drop="Label_Drop" AllowDrop="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Below are my CodeBehind Events

```
Label DraggingLabel;
private void Label_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DraggingLabel = sender as Label;
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(DraggingLabel, DraggingLabel.Content, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void Label_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Label originalsource = e.OriginalSource as Label;
    Label lblToDrop = sender as Label;
    string fromContent = lblToDrop.Content.ToString();
    lblToDrop.Content = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
    DraggingLabel.Content = fromContent;
}
```

So basically i created a global Label DraggingLabel to use it at Label_Drop to interchange the Text.

Final Output.

[image]

Good Luck.